# How can I add a control like a DateTimePicker to my office ribbon I'm creating using visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, vb.net-2010, ribbon

I'm creating an Microsoft Office 2010 add-in ribbon with a bunch of controls on it.  I am able to add things like buttons, TextBoxes, and Labels.  :-) I am not, however, able to add the one control I need, which is a `DateTimePicker`. :-(  Is there some workaround or hack to getting other controls like a DateTimePicker on my ribbon?

If it helps any, I'm using Visual Basic 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up just making one of my buttons open up a separate form which then was able to have the `DateTimePicker` control on it. :-)